# Can you add a fan control unit to a system with no fan control?

Tags: fan, cooling, temperature

#### Background:

I have a new-to-me [NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage). The chassis fan is exceedingly loud for the room it is in and is always at full speed.

The motherboard chassis fan (CHAFAN1) socket has three pins. The plug that fits into it has four, but only three wires connecting to the fan. In the BIOS, under "IT8772E HW Monitor", I can see the CPU temperature. The CPU Fan Speed marked N/A, and there is no mention of the system temperature or system/chassis fan Speed.

I conclude that there is no motherboard support for chassis fan control, and even if there was, the fan itself can only be controlled by voltage. (If that is wrong, I would love to hear it!)

### Solution?

I wonder if there are devices I can buy that connect between the 3-pin fan socket and then 3-pin fan that directly measures the temperature of the system and controls the fan speed, without motherboard support.

Or even a replacement fan that will do all that itself.

I'm not looking for a brand-name or particular recommendations. I am looking for official names and search terms - because when I look for fan controllers, I find devices to help control 8 fans from one 4-pin source, or over-the-top custom case mods.

Comment: a 3 pin fan is a single speed fan. A 4 pin fan is a multi-speed fan. If the motherboard has 4 pins, replacing the fan with one that has all 4 pins in use will make the fan work on lower speeds too.

Comment: @LPChip: As above, the motherboard has 3 pins. I understand that it is possible to control the speed of 3-pin fans by lowering the voltage on the (putative) +12V pin #2.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that information. You do then need a controller in between. I can't give recommendations for that though, but you might want to look at other cooler pins

Comment: Other cooler pins? There are others? Huh!

Comment: I mean, the motherboard may have both 3pin connections and 4pin connections. The CPU usually has a 4pin, and some chassis fans have 3pins.

Comment: What CPU does the NAS use, and how heavily? It may be that you can simply use a quieter fan (or undervplt the current one) leaving the CPU to throttle to regulate temp. I ran I a first gen Intel i3 CPU for years on passive cooling and under clocking it.

Comment: @davidgo: Celeron J1900 @ 2 GHz - say that is 27 watts, but by the time you add 4 drives, motherboard, memory... I reckon around 200 W, give or take.

Comment: That CPU is 10 watts according to Intel ark. I can't see that system drawing anything like 200 watts typical- I'd imagine well less then 100 watts typical. As it uses an entry level Intel CPU I'd simply replace the fan with a quieter one or undervolt the existing one and let the CPU throttle down if it gets to hot.

Comment: If you want to get really fancy you may be able to attach a heat sensor. I've not tried this, but have a look at https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/temperature-controlled-dc-fan-using-thermistor/ for a simple diy project.